# SQL: Select the min of a subtraction of two columns, and also select the numbers used in the min subtraction

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, min, difference

I have two columns, I want to select: the Price, the min abs. difference between Price and Strike, and the Strike the corresponds to the min abs. difference calculation. I am new to SQL, so forgive me if this is easy.

```
Price   Strike
30.8    29
30.8    30
30.8    31
30.2    29
30.2    30
30.2    31
```

The answer I want to get is:

```
Price  Diff  Strike
30.8   .2    31
30.2   .2    30
```

The code I have so far is:

```
Select min(price) as 'Price',
min(abs(price - Strike)) as 'Diff'
from Table
group by price
```

I don't know how to properly get the corresponding strike to be selected.

Thank you kindly

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Windows Server Management Studio.

I apologize if this is not specific enough, I am very new to SQL

Comment: Do you want to get the minimum difference for each price, or the minimum difference overall?

Answer (score 4):

I will use `Window Function` to do this.

```
SELECT Price,
       Diff,
       Strike
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Abs(price - Strike) Diff,
               Row_number()OVER(partition BY price ORDER BY Abs(price - Strike) )rn
        FROM   Yourtable) a
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Or if there is tie in min value of `Abs(price - Strike)` per `price` group and if want all rows with same min value then use `Dense_Rank`

```
SELECT Price,
       Diff,
       Strike
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Abs(price - Strike) Diff,
               Dense_Rank()OVER(partition BY price ORDER BY Abs(price - Strike) )rn
        FROM   Yourtable) a
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: I would use `RANK()` in case there's a tie ... you could have more than one pair of `(price,strike)` with the minimum difference as in the OP. `ROW_NUMBER()` will get only one.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is through window functions (specifically `RANK()`):

```
SELECT price, strike, difference
  FROM (
    SELECT price, strike, ABS(price - strike) AS difference
         , RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY ABS(price - strike) ) AS rn
      FROM mytable
) x
 WHERE x.rn = 1;
```

You could also use `DENSE_RANK()` (it won't matter in this case).